# Designing file reader for multiple file formats/headers

Tags: c++, file-handling, class-design

I'm trying to design a `Reader` class, that would be able to read multiple file types (mostly binary representation of something).
To get all the metadata from the file, it's going to use `Header` class which will somehow tell the `Reader` class size of the file header, (maybe through static field, idk) num bytes to read and pass to a header at the first read. Header class will parse a header accordingly, and will provide some abstract methods like `std::size_t getChunkSize()`. Then, header class will tell the reader number of bytes for each chunk of data. That what i have in mind. How can i properly represent this hierarchy or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "represent"? Do you want some UML?

Comment: @ACB i prefer c++ code or pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally implementing a generic `Reader` class for binary formats can be quite challenging.
Since some file formats have variable length headers I would suggest to put the reading of the header completely into the `Header` class.
Something like:

```
struct Header {
 virtual size_t parse(uint8_t* buf, size_t len) = 0;
 virtual int getNumChunks() const = 0;
 virtual size_t getChunkSize(int chunk) = 0;
}
```

then in your `Reader` class you can have a read method which first parses the `Header` and then reads the rest of the file based on the chunk size. An offset method to get the start of the chunk would also be helpful for some file formats. Depending on the file formats you want to parse there may also be problems of actually determining the chunk size if there are no chunk headers and you have variable length arrays in those chunks for example. As such it would maybe be a better idea to also implement a `Chunk` class to read all the chunks.

Comment: yeah, that's almost look like my current implementation :D But, how `Reader` class will know what's the header size (on the first read, and then pass a buffer to be parsed to a header `parse` method)? He needs to know it from the `Header` class i suppose, which is going to be derived from an abstract `Header` class.

Comment: Just read in the whole file from disk and then prase it. Much faster anyways.

Comment: yeah, but i mean, header size can very differ, what if `Reader` class read less data than a header itself? `Reader` need's to know it before he is going to read this first chunk i believe. so that's why i'm thinking of some static `::header_size` field, which is going to tell reader a num bytes to read and pass to a `Header` class

Comment: Just return the number of bytes read from the `parse` method in the header and pass that method the whole file. Or use streams and simply continue to read from the stream where the `Header` left off. In case you have to few bytes just throw an error in `parse`

Comment: yep, that's an option, thx